# Shopware 6 Schedule Content

Tags: symfony, e-commerce, shopware

We currently try to find a shopsystem, that fits our needs. So we did not find the functionality of schedule content in Shopware 6.

We need the availability to set a time for when the content is published on the page and when it is "unpublished".

Does Shopware 6 or Symfony have such functionality out of the box or by an extension?

Comment: Please be a bit more precise. What do you mean with "content"? A product? a CMS page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not out of the box in Shopware 6 (yet) but someone in the community developed this functionality as a plugin.

You can find it here: https://store.shopware.com/en/hatsl79289836507/products-layouts/pages-scheduler.html